# how image size and resolution correlate in JPEG format

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, jpeg

I have a photo with a size and pixel diemensions as shown below:

[image]

[image]

I opened and saved it using Matlab, and the size of this photo becomes much smaller, and also a smaller dpi value. But the diemension is still the same.

[image] 
[image]

Then I converted the two to .bmp format, and the bmp images are in the same size! Does the dpi value correlate to image size, or there are other reasons behind?

Comment: The resolution (DPI) is just Exif tag; there is no correlation with the image size.

Comment: The dpi is only really relevant when you come to printing an image.

Comment: (1) The size depends on the compression-parameters and the data itself (e.g. noise) (2) Evaluating the BMP from both does not mean anything. If no compression in BMP is used, resolution and color-channels are the same, the size is equal (a completely black image too). (3) Your BMP-outputs will probably be different. Read them in, subtract from each other and look for nonzeros. (4) You really should look up some introduction to lossy vs. lossless compression.

Answer (score 0):

When an image is described as 7952× 5304 pixels, then the dpi value is of no consequence. It means nothing.
Where the dpi value comes in, is in describing how large the image will be printed.

You can always resize the image to the dimensions you want with imresize.